# SQL server management studio - How to connect to SQL server using connection string?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I cannot connect to SQL Server by using SQL Server Management Studio. 
I have a connection string:

```
 <add name="AccountConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=MyIP;Initial Catalog=nvm;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myID;Password=myPassWord" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have tried to connect by entering myIP to Servername, MyID to Login and myPassword to password but still unable to connect. This is the result:

[image]

Does anyone has ideas ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you entering an IP address (myIP) to connect to the server as opposed to an instance name? If so the provider is Named Pipes so this will not work.

Comment: I entered that IP to Server name field in "connect to server" popup on Mysql Server Management Studio.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? And what version?

Comment: it's SQL Server 2012

Comment: Does the connection string work in other environments? i.e. from code? If so and the "Data Source" is an IP address then in the "Connect to Server" options tab pick "TCP/IP" in the network protocol drop down.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do and I don't think it's possible with SSMS.  After trying it several ways myself, I ended up going with a solution that executes SSMS from the command line, with arguments. Unfortunately, connection string isn't one of those arguments, but with the other CLI arguments you can achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using Username and a Password to connect to a database, you should change your connection string to look something like this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=False;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

If you are wondering why:

> Integrated Security When false, User ID and Password are specified in
>   the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are
>   used for authentication. Recognized values are true, false, yes, no,
>   and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true. If User
>   ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true,
>   the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will
>   be used.

P.S

***If this is not helping then you may check this also:***

Make sure your database engine is configured to accept remote
 connections:

> Start > All Programs > SQL Server 2005 > Configuration
>
> > Tools > SQL Server Surface Area Configuration Click on Surface Area
> >
> > Configuration for Services and Connections Select the instance that is
> >
> > having a problem > Database Engine > Remote Connections Enable local
> >     and remote connections Restart instance

You may need to create an exception on the firewall for the SQL Server instance and port you are using:

> Start > Run > Firewall.cpl Click on exceptions tab Add sqlservr.exe
>
> (typically located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>
> Server\MSSQL.x\MSSQL\Bin, check your installs for the actual folder
>
> path) and port (default is 1433) Check your connection string as well

Comment: That connection string is using in code and it's working fine. What I'm trying is connect to the database via SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: You can use the connection string in SSMS, but it transmits the credentials in plain text, so IMHO it's not appropriate for a production server

Comment: Does the credentials go from client to sql sqlserver as plain text? If so is there any way to secure it?

Comment: @variable Usually you are accessing database from a backend ( server, or whatever app is using it.). You could encrypt conn string as a simple string and before using it in your app you could decrypt it, if you are afraid of keeping conn string as a plain text.

Comment: No, I meant to ask, whether the connection from the application backend to the database happens in plain text?

Answer (score 0):

try to put IP address

```
<add key="AccountConnStr" value="Data Source=192.168.2.1\SQLSERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=nvm;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword"/>
```

and put IP and Domain in etc/Host File and also try to test ping your server ip is it reachable from your computer .
Enable remote connections on the instance of SQL Server that you want to connect to from a remote computer.
and make sure that checkbox Allow remote connections to this server is selected .